# PHP Imagick ReadImage WriteImage different quality

Tags: php, imagick

I am scaling images with php-imagick. The image I want to scale is a jpg without exif data (1600x1200+0+0 8-bit sRGB). The quality of the scaled image is lower than the original. By quality I mean that the image has more artifacts (visible quality). So I made a test where I simply read an image and write it under another filename without chaning anything else:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage(realpath('./a.jpg')); // image quality checked with $im->getImageCompressionQuality() 50
$im->writeImage('./b.jpg'); // image quality checked with $im->getImageCompressionQuality() 50
```

The result is:

- Image a.jpg > 254kb (original image)
- Image b.jpg > 183kb

So by simply writing the image to a new file, php-imagick changes something that I don't want.
Can anyone explain to me:

- What happens to the generated image?
- How can I write the image without changing any other stuff except scaling?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is the default JPEG compression quality is lower than you expect, [Imagick::setImageCompressionQuality](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php) and  [Imagick::getImageCompressionQuality](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagecompressionquality.php)

Comment: If you compress compressed data it can (and mostly will) become even larger. Same for **not** lossless image compression. The quality gets worse every time. You can add a quality parameter for writeImage(). Chose a better one.

Comment: As written in my example code: I don't change the compression, nor the quality. I just read and directly write the image. So, does that mean, that a default compression gets used when writing the image?

Comment: From my experience, generally yes. The original quality setting is only worthwhile for the first compression. Your subsequent re-compression is working with a re-consituted image, this is the challenge of processing with lossy compresison.

What I suggest doing is save a high quality image at various qualities, like 100, 90, 80 quality, and run it through your PHP script, try playing with the two functions I mentioned above, and try to find a good balance from the reprocessed output.